# Delete from multiple SQL tables with C# command

Tags: c#, sql

I want to delete from multiple SQL tables with a C# command but I get always error:

> Invalid syntax near ",".

Here is code so far:

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=" + System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Server.ini") + ";" + "Initial Catalog=" + "lin2world" + ";" + "User ID=" + System.IO.File.ReadAllText("User.ini") + ";" + "Password=" + System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Password.ini");
string sql = "DELETE FROM user_data, user_item, user_ActiveSkill, user_blocklist, user_deleted, user_friend, user_henna, user_history, user_log, user_macro, user_macroinfo, user_newbie, user_nobless, user_punish, user_recipe, user_skill, user_sociality, user_subjob WHERE char_id='" + textBox1.Text + "' ";
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
connection.Open();
dataadapter.Fill(ds, "char_id");
connection.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Character Deleted!!");
```

Comment: SQL Server has no syntax to delete from multiple tables in one statement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714545/delete-rows-from-multiple-tables-using-a-single-query-sql-express-2005-with-a

Comment: That's not the correct syntax for DELETE.  It doesn't look like you even have a table name in there anywhere.  DELETE is used to delete rows from a table; are you trying to clear the values in certain columns but leave the row in the table?

Comment: try putting `test' GO DROP TABLE user_data GO` in textbox1

Comment: what I would do is put seperate deletions into a transaction. read this other answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783726/how-do-i-delete-from-multiple-tables-using-inner-join-in-sql-server

Comment: Write a stored procedure to clear the tables and call it. Also please look into parameterized queries, this is a sql injection vector **nightmare**.

Comment: You can still do this with a cursor and a select based on your list of names, see below. Also yes as sawyer says, please, please, don't do this without using a parameterized query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do something similar to this, you can pass all tables as a list and still do what you want.

```
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT name 
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
WHERE name IN ("user_data","user_item","user_ActiveSkill","user_blocklist","user_deleted","user_friend","user_henna","user_history","user_log","user_macro","user_macroinfo","user_newbie","user_nobless","user_punish","user_recipe","user_skill","user_sociality","user_subjob")  -- use these databases

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   

       DELETE FROM @name WHERE char_id='whatever'

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   
END
```

Edit: It seems like these are all related tables -- if you have a proper relationship with cascade: delete, you should only have to delete the main record and its children will all take care of themselves

Answer (score 4):

You can only delete from one table in a delete statement.

Use multiple delete statements within a transaction to perform the deletes

In case your not familiar with transactions in C# here is an example

```
using (var Conn = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString))
{
    SqlTransaction trans = null;
    try
    {
        Conn.Open();
        trans = Conn.BeginTransaction();

        using (SqlCommand Com = new SqlCommand(ComText, Conn, trans))
        {
            /* DB work */
        }
        trans.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        if (trans != null) trans.Rollback();
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use triggers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996643/sql-server-on-delete-trigger

Or some form of cascading delete if it's applicable.

Comment: Cascading delete makes the most sense here i'd say.

Comment: @Yablargo I agree only if the tables are truly relational, Since we don't know the table structure we can't really say that the id is set up as a foreign key in the other tables though.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete from multiple tables in one statement within SQL Server. You will need multiple statements, one for each table:

```
DELETE FROM user_data WHERE PersonID = '2';
DELETE FROM user_item WHERE PersonID = '2';
```

etc etc

And fire each one off individually, (making sure not to violate any FKs) or create a stored procedure and fire that off (to minimise open and closing of db connections).

My experience of using triggers tells me not to use triggers, at times they will not fire when they should!