# how to use select and delete in one query

Tags: mysql

i have table AAA and BBB

table AAA

| ID | Name | Token |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Anna | dwdwdwdd |
| 2 | Bob | rererere |
| 3 | Cindy | gfgfgfgf |

table BBB

| ID | AAA_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 3 |

How can I delete from two tables in one query

for example, I need to delete from the AAA table where the token = rererere and at the same time delete AAA_ID from the BBB table

how can i do this please help...

Comment: Create FOREIGN KEY with ON DELETE CASCADE. Then simply delete from main table - and related rows from slave table will be deleted automatically.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=baaa1bdb519193bfad4d4225cf2159e1

Comment: @ysth: Oh sorry, let me edit my comment.

For MS SQL Server, It seems that You cannot `DELETE` from multiple tables with a single expression. Or you have to use a TRIGGER. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714545/delete-rows-from-multiple-tables-using-a-single-query-sql-express-2005-with-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the best way to handle this would be to use cascading deletion.  Consider the following schema definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE AAA (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Token VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE BBB (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    AAA_ID INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (AAA_ID) REFERENCES AAA (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Using the above schema, deleting a record from the `AAA` table will automatically cause any records in the `BBB` table which are linked via the `AAA_ID` foreign key to also be deleted.

Actually, on MySQL you *can* delete from two or more tables at once, using delete join syntax.  So the following query should be able to achieve the same thing as cascading deletion, if you can't make the schema change for some reason.

```sql
DELETE a, b     -- specify both aliases to target both AAA and BBB
FROM AAA a
INNER JOIN BBB b
    ON b.AAA_ID = a.ID
WHERE a.Token = 'rererere';
```

Answer (score 0):

ON DELETE CASCADE constraint is used in MySQL to delete the rows from the child table automatically, when the rows from the parent table are deleted. For example when a student registers in an online learning platform, then all the details of the student are recorded with their unique number/id.

example to create foreign key with cascade in mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE Enroll (
sno INT,
cno INT,
jdate date,
PRIMARY KEY(sno,cno),
FOREIGN KEY(sno) 
    REFERENCES Student(sno)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
FOREIGN KEY(cno) 
    REFERENCES Course(cno)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
```

);